# Screenshot of hidden div using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

How to take screenshots of a hidden div?
The code given below is not working for hidden div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;" >  
 <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id="canvas" style="display:none;">
<p>Canvas:</p>
</div>

 <div id="image">

  </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
  var elem = $('#printDiv');
        html2canvas(elem, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = data;
                document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
            }
        });

</script>
```

It works when we set the style of the div "mydiv" as 'display:block'.

Answer (score 32):

```
html2canvas(mydiv, {
    onclone: function (clonedDoc) {
        clonedDoc.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';
    }
}).then((canvas)=>{
//your onrendered function code here
})
```

Comment: jQuery version: `$(clonedDoc).find('#mydiv').css('display', 'block');`

Answer (score 19):

You can use opacity set to 0. Here is sample example:

```
<div style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.0;">
    <div id="tempImageThumbnail"></div>
</div>
var tempImageThumb = $('#tempImageThumbnail');
tempImageThumb.append("<div>some text</div>");

html2canvas([tempImageThumb.get(0)], {
    onrendered : function(canvas) {
         document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
});
```

Comment: With newest version of html2canvas.js.  
These code works well as `onrendered` had been deprecated for a long time.  

Part-1  

`<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55; opacity: 0.0;"><h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4> </div>`

Comment: Part-2  
`<script type="text/javascript"> $('#btn-click').on('click', function() { html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture"), { removeContainer: false, onclone: function(doc) { div = $(doc).find('#capture'); div.css('opacity', '1.0'); } }).then(canvas => { document.body.appendChild(canvas) console.log(canvas); var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); console.log(imagedata); }); }) </script>`

Answer (score 5):

The following code worked for me. I am using Angular with jsPdf and html2canvas libraries

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("pdfTable"), {
  onclone: function (clonedDoc) {

     // I made the div hidden and here I am changing it to visible
    clonedDoc.getElementById('pdfTable').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}).then(canvas => {
  // The following code is to create a pdf file for the taken screenshot
  var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [canvas.width, canvas.height]);
  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("PNG", 1.0);
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 0, 0, (canvas.width), (canvas.height));
  pdf.save('converteddoc.pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

html2canvas provides an option called '**onclone**' by passing the cloned document. You can set the visibility of your hidden element there.

```
onclone: function(doc){
    hiddenDiv = doc.getElementById('myDiv');
    hiddenDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: jQuery version: `$(clonedDoc).find('#mydiv').css('display', 'block');`

Answer (score 4):

This is working:

`<div style="width:0;height:0;overflow: hidden">
   <div>
     content to screenshot
   </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a out of the box way to achieve this. How about showing the div, capture and then hide it again?

```
var elem = $('#printDiv');

html2canvas(elem, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        elem.show();
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
        elem.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "visibility: none" instead of "display: none" in the div and change the following in html2canvas.js script file - In function parseElement change

```
 if (getCSS(el, 'display') !== "none" && getCSS(el, 'visibility') !== "hidden")
```

to

```
if (getCSS(el, 'display') !== "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a canvas function and then you can show and hide based on it. I'm also using jsPDF to convert images to pdf. like this

```
   function generateCanvas() {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#yourid"), {
            scrollX: 0,
            scrollY: -window.scrollY
        }).then(canvas => {
            //var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 2.0);
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'jpeg',
                quality: 1.0
            });
    
        $("#canvas_container").attr("src", imgData);
            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 180, 150);  // 180x150 mm @ (10,10)mm
            pdf.save("download.pdf");
        });
    }
    
    $("#download_pdf").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#yourid").show();
        generateCanvas();
        $("#yourid").hide();
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Firstly, i dare say: This solution will work fine for all cases `إن شاء الله`

---

> Since this Solution based on jQuery API , Don't Use `hide/show` but use `fadeOut/fadeIn`  instead.

## SCRIPT :

```
<script>

           var elem = $('#printDiv');
            if(!elem.is(":visible")){
                elem.show();elem.fadeIn(1);elem.fadeOut(1);
             }
            html2canvas(elem, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                  //your staff here
                }
            });
    
    </script>
```

---

NOTE :
We use this repository [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/) , the syntax will be `then` function instead of `onrendered` callback :

```
<script>

           var elem = $('#printDiv');
            if(!elem.is(":visible")){
                elem.show();elem.fadeIn(1);elem.fadeOut(1);
             }
            html2canvas(elem).then(function (canvas) {
                  //your staff here
                }
            );
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Please don't use this, html2canvas has a method that allows you to play with cloned document element styles… take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38556127/3632172